# White line on hover

Tags: html, css

When I hover over the div there is a white line on the outside of the div. 
I've tried with text-decoration: none;

Any idea how to remove this?

This is the html

```
<a href="/" style="color:white">
  <div class="headerOption">
    <p>
      Home
    </p>
  </div>
</a>
```

SCSS

```
 .headerOption {
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 6vw;
    height: 2.8vw;
    font-size: 0.97vw;
    font-weight: 500;
    @include normal;
    font-family: "Rubik-Medium", sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;

    p {
        position: relative;
        top: 30%;
    }

    &:active {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    }

    &:hover {
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);

    }


}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you include your CSS too please.

Comment: I think you meant `text-decoration: none;`.

Comment: yeah, sorry. fixed it

Comment: What is the 'normal' ?

Comment: The CSS you provided does not match up to the image you've provided.

Comment: @Sam   font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: center; it's being overwritten though but that's not what's causing the issue.

Comment: @Albzi that is the styling for that div so in what way doesn't it match up?

Comment: With the colourings and paddings.

Comment: ah. well that's because it's a screenshot. The colouring isn't going to affect it is it?

Comment: @Naomi - that's not quite the right attitude. Please do all that you can to make your posts accurate and unencumbered by the need to imagine what you actually mean and have coded.

Comment: I've just provided the image to show the white line. Unfortunately I can't provide the whole code. I provided the code that is relevant for this issue.

Comment: https://codepen.io/naomilea/pen/aWydpM here is a codepen, it doesn't seem to have the issue here though.

Comment: Problem solved, turns out it was bootstrap's styling overriding mine. !important solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've actually got your CSS in the wrong order I think.

You're setting:

```
.headerOption a{whatever: somevalue;}
```

On:

```
<a>
    <div class="headerOption"></div>
</a>
```

It's looking to style an anchor tag inside the div, but there isn't one.

Comment: still not removing the white line

Comment: Please don't add notes about your edits to your posts. You should be providing a description of your edit in the "Edit Summary" field when you're authoring your edit.